# Laravel : Create Button returns the same view but blank and does not create any record

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel and I am working on creating a CMS. I have created a view to create posts but after I input data and click create to submit, page refreshes and shows the same view but with no input and no record created, when it should show a flash message and return the posts index view.

Here is my VIEW HTML:

```
@section('content')
<div class="card card-default">
    <div class="card-header">
       {{ isset($post) ? 'Edit Post' : 'Create Post' }}
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <form action="{{ isset($post) ? route('posts.update', $post->id) : route('posts.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            @if (isset($post))
                @Method('PUT')
            @endif
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" value="{{isset($post) ? $post->title : ""}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="5" rows="3" class="form-control">{{isset($post) ? $post->description : ""}}</textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="content">Content</label>
                <input id="content" type="hidden" name="content" value="{{isset($post) ? $post->content : ""}}">
                <trix-editor input="content"></trix-editor>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="published_at">Published at</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="published_at" id="published_at" value="{{isset($post) ? $post->published_at : ""}}">
            </div>
            
            @if (isset($post))
                <div class="form-group">
                    <img src="{{ asset('/storage/'.$post->image) }}" alt="" style="width: 100%">
                </div>
            @endif

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="category">Category</label>
                <select name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
                    @foreach($categories as $category)
                        <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->title}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="image">Image</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" id="image">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                   {{ isset($post) ? 'Update Post' : 'Create Post' }}
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

@endsection

Here is METHOD:

```
public function store(CreatePostRequest $request)
{
    $image = $request->image->store('posts');

    Post::create([
        'title'=>$request->title,
        'description'=>$request->description,
        'image'=>$image,
        'content'=>$request->content,
        'published_at' => $request->published_at,
        'category_id' => $request->category
    ]);

    session()->flash('success', 'Post Created Successfully');

    return redirect(route('posts.index'));

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: maybe it isn't passing validation, so it is returning back and you are not displaying errors

Comment: try `dd($image)` after `$image` in controller. Probably the problem is here. And use `return redirect()->route('posts.index);` instead of yours.

Comment: I tried the dd($image) but still nothing, only refreshes the page and deletes the content entered. I think it is not reaching the method at all :/

Comment: I think it is not passing the validation as the @lagbox mentioned. I changed it to request()->all() and it works